# How to clear default value of Intvar() in tkinter display in entry widget is 0?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

```
val1=IntVar()
val2=IntVar()
val3=IntVar()
val4=StringVar()
```

I have declared four variables, all first three display `0` on `tkinter` GUI `Entry` widgets. So how to clear it?

Comment: Use `IntVar(value="")`.

Comment: @acw1668: that's not very good advice, because calling the `.get()` method on a intvar that has been set in this way will return an error. `IntVar`s are designed to hold integers, not strings.

Comment: @BryanOakley Even though without `value=""`, user can still remove the `0` in the `Entry` widget.  So it is the responsibility of the developer to cater such situation.  My suggestion is just to answer what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Integers can't be empty because they only hold numbers.

Comment: ok thanks for commenting but I know is there any other opinion.